# UITabBar padding

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Is there a ways to adjust the width of the padding between Cocoa Touch UITabBar buttons? I'm working on an iPad project and I would like to reduce the padding between buttons for a slightly tighter look. Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a close look at [`TabBarKit`](https://github.com/davidmorford/TabBarKit) and see if it suits your requirements. It doesn't explicitly mention that you can adjust spacing etc, but at least the code isn't a black box which would enable you to see if adding such functionality is within the realm of possibility.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I was hoping to do it with native controls, but like you say, it appears that UITabBar is a black box.